# beautiful souphelp with defining the search criteria

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website with terms and their english translation and explanation. I have managed with Beautiful Soup and Request to get the tr or td entries, but I wonder whether someone could suggest how to refine my request to extract only the term and the explanation? I think that it is impossible to separate the english translation from the rest though?? The 'table' from the actual website is a combination of 19 tables(http://www.nodimarinari.it/Protopage10.html). The following is one entry

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="124">
<div align="center"><b><font color="#000066">tabella delle maree</font></b></div>
</td>
<td align="left" width="616"><font color="#000066"> (s.f.) (Maree) tide
table Tabella che riporta, per una determinata zona, l'andamento della
marea, cioe' giorno ed ora delle massime/minime e le relative variazioni
dei livelli delle acque. </font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="124">
<div align="center"><font color="#000066"><b></b></font></div>
</td>
<td align="left" width="616"><font color="#000066"></font></td>
</tr>
```

Ideally I would like to get 'tabella delle maree','tide table', 'Tabella che riporta... '

Comment: could you add the code you've already tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my results that according to my understanding of your question. Let me know if this what you're trying to achieve.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("http://www.nodimarinari.it/Protopage10.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
words = soup.find_all("font", color="#000066")

num = 0
term = []
explanation = []

for word in words:
    if len(word.text) > 1:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            term.append(word.text)
        elif num % 2 == 1:
            explanation.append(str(word.text).replace("\n", ""))
        num += 1

for i in range(0, len(term)):
    print(term[i] + ": " + explanation[i] + "\n")
```

Output:

```
abbandonare:  (v.) (Emergenze) to abandon L'attodi lasciare la imbarcazione pericolante da parte del capitano e dell'equipaggio,dopo aver esaurito tutti i tentativi suggeriti dall'arte nautica. 

abbisciare:  (v.) (Cavi e nodi) to range, tojag Preparare su uno spazio piano un cavo od una catena, ad ampie spire,in modo che il cavo o la catena possano svolgersi liberamente e scorreresenza impedimenti. 

abbittare:  (v.) (Cavi e nodi) to bitt Legareun cavo o una catena ad una bitta. 

abbonacciare:  (v.) (Vento e Mare) to becalm, tofall calm Il calmarsi del vento e del mare 

abbordaggio:  (s.m.) [A]. (Abbordi) collisionUrto o collisione accidentale tra imbarcazioni. La legislazione marittimaprevede un'ampio corredo di "norme per evitare l'abbordo in mare" checostituiscono la regolamentazione di base della navigazione [B]. a. intenzionaleboarding, running foul Investire intenzionalmente un'altra imbarcazionecon l'obiettivo di danneggiarla o affondarla. Anticamente si chiamavaanche "arrembaggio" 

abbordare:  (v.) (A bordo) to collide, to board,to run into vedi "abbordaggio". 

abbordo:  (s.m.) (Abbordi) collision Equivalentemoderno del termine "abbordaggio". 

abbozzare:  (v.) (Cavi e nodi) to stop Trattenerecon una legatura provvisoria, detta bozza, un cavo od una catena tesa,per evitarne lo scorrimento durante il tempo necessario per legarla definitivamente.

...
...
...


vogare:  (v.) (Remi) to row Sinonimodi "remare". 


volta:  (s.f.) [A]. (Cavi enodi) bitter, wrap Indica comunemente un giro di un cavo o di una catenaattorno ad una bitta o ad un altro attrezzo atto a trattenere la cimastessa. [B]. dar v. (Manovre) to cleat, to belay, to make fast Legareuna cima od una catena attorno ad una bitta o una galloccia, con o senzanodi. 

zattera di salvataggio:  (s.f.) (A bordo) liferaftVedi "autogonfiabile". 

zavorra:  (s.f.) (Terminologia)ballast Pesi che vengono disposti a bordo dell'imbarcazione, normalmenteil piu' in basso possibile nella chiglia, per equilibrare la spinta lateraledel vento ed il conseguente movimento di rollio e di sbandata. Normalmentetali pesi sono in piombo e nei velieri moderni e' la lama di deriva stessa,costruita con metalli pesanti, ad essere zavorrata. In alcune particolarivelieri da regata la zavorra e' costituita da acqua di mare che puo' esserepompata in apposite casse (dal lato sopravvento) quando necessario. 

zenit:  (s.m.) (Geografia) zenitPunto della sfera celeste che si trova esattamente sulla verticale aldi sopra del luogo di osservazione. 

zinco:  (s.m.) (Varie) zinc,zinc plate Metallo dotato di particolari caratteristiche elettrolitichecol quale si realizzano piastre ed elementi (chiamati anodi) che vengonoutilizzati per evitare la corrosione di elementi metallici immersi adopera delle correnti galvaniche.Tali elementi vengono posizionati nellaparte immersa dello scafo, in corrispondenza di parti metalliche, in particolaredell'elica e della zavorra, e nel tempo si consumano evitando la corrosionedelle parti metalliche contigue. Per questo vengono anche chiamati zinchisacrificali.
```

Explanation:

So I used BeautifulSoup to parse all the terms and their meanings. To do that I had to parse all the text inside all the `<font color="#000066">` elements inside the html code.

The `words` list contain the data in the following format:

```
[<font color="#000066">A</font>, <font color="#000066"> </font>, <font color="#000066"><b></b></font>, <font color="#000066"></font>, <font color="#000066">abbandonare</font>, <font color="#000066"> (v.) (Emergenze) to abandon L'atto
di lasciare la imbarcazione pericolante da parte del capitano e dell'equipaggio,
dopo aver esaurito tutti i tentativi suggeriti dall'arte nautica. </font>, <font color="#000066"><b></b></font>, <font color="#000066"></font>, <font color="#000066">abbisciare</font>, <font color="#000066"> (v.) (Cavi e nodi) to range, to
jag Preparare su uno spazio piano un cavo od una catena, ad ampie spire, ETC.]
```

The if condition `if len(word.text) > 1:` is used to ignore the single literals parsed (e.g: ['A', 'B', ..., 'Z']), that way we only deal with the terms and the meanings.

The next if condition `if num % 2 == 0:` is used to move all the terms from the `words` list to a list called `term` which is meant to contain only terms.

The last if condition `if num % 2 == 1:` is used to to move all the explanations from the `words` list to a list called `explanation` which is meant to contain only explanations.

The last for loop is for printing purposes only.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect. I will need to go through your code to understand it though. Not sure how/why it works at the minute. Could you take the time to explain the code please.

Comment: I just updated my answer with some explanations. Let me know if you want me to clarify anything.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I really don't understand the if num%2 ==0 and if num%2 ==1 conditions. Could this logic be used to extract the english translation contained within the explanation part of the text as well? Grateful for the trouble that you are going to

Comment: Hi @user1478335 I'm glad that I can help you out , and yes I believe it should work. If you want me to double check, you can always try the website with the english terms and see if the logic is retrieving the data correctly.